# Why are the dead keys not working on Intellij on Kubuntu 21.10?

Tags: intellij-idea, layout, keyboard, fcitx

On Kubuntu 21.10, the dead keys do not work on Intellij.
I have two keyboard set up: plain US english and US english with dead keys. Those do not work even when I select the correct keyboard layout using KDE settings editor.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question:

The settings seem to look for a fcitx package, even displaying an error like "fcitx not found on dbus". The package is fcitx5, the old version seems to be fcitx.

Installing the fcitx5 package then reloading Intellij solved the problem.

`sudo apt install fcitx5`

Then restart Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check:

```
ibus-daemon -rd
```

[For more details about it](https://superuser.com/questions/708538/on-ubuntu-13-10-multiple-hits-on-ctrltab-makes-my-intellij-13-keyboard-stuck-n/716440#716440)